# Do I need to create separate index for primary key of relational database table

Tags: database, indexing, derby, create-table

If I create table with primary key is index automatically created for the table or does that need doing separately.

i.e if this is the table ddl

```
 CREATE TABLE release(guid varchar(36) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
name varchar(255),xmldata  CLOB(512 K))
```

do I also need to do

```
CREATE INDEX release_idx ON release(guid)
```

or not

(I'm using Derby a database that comes with Java)

Comment: This all documented in the manual: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.9/ref/rrefsqlj13590.html#rrefsqlj13590 (see the section "Backing indexes")

Comment: "NOT NULL" is also unnecessary when you set  "PRIMARY KEY".

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You don't need to. The primary key is already an index.

Comment: Good to know I thought so but wasn't sure

Comment: @Jon Just out of curiosity does the performance of query improve if we built again an index on primary key?

Comment: The `PRIMARY KEY` is also `UNIQUE` _in MySQL_.

Comment: @RickJames PRIMARY KEY has to be unique by it's definition. Not only in MySQL but in every rdbms

Comment: Sorry for being pedantic, but the primary key is a constraint, not an index.

Comment: The Derby Reference Guide mentions that [Derby automatically creates an index](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.14/ref/rrefsqlj20937.html) when you add a primary key constraint.  In this way your primary key will get an index automatically.  The Derby Reference also mentions how to find the name of the auto-created index which backs the primary key constraint.