# Separate column index VS Multiple

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a table with 3 columns `id  safeid  branchid`

-some times I need to get records by `safeid` so I have a `safeid (INDEX)`

-some times I need to get records by `branchid` so I have a `branchid (INDEX)`

-some times I need to get records by `safeid` and `branchid` together . so the question is : Do I have to create another `branchid_safeid (INDEX)` for the two columns together to make selection faster?

Another Question

the `id` column is a unique primary key .. Do I need to create `id (INDEX)` or the primary key is an index by itself

Answer (score 2):

(I reopened because the "dups" only answered the second question.)

**Question #1:**  For `WHERE safeid = 123 AND branchid = 234`, you need `INDEX(safeid, branchid)` in either order.  Better yet, have *two* indexes:

```
INDEX(safeid, branchid),  -- for the pair, or for just `safeid`
INDEX(branchid)           -- for branchid
```

This would take care of the 3 cases you mention.

More discussion [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).

**Question #2:**  As for "Another question", in MySQL (InnoDB specifically), the `PRIMARY KEY` is 'clustered' with the data; it is `UNIQUE`; and it is an `INDEX`.  There is essentially no reason to duplicate the `PRIMARY KEY` with the addition of a separate `UNIQUE KEY` or `INDEX`.

Here are the "dups" that were previously quoted:

[Is the primary key automatically indexed in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071180/is-the-primary-key-automatically-indexed-in-mysql)
[Do I need to create separate index for primary key of relational database table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14646014/do-i-need-to-create-separate-index-for-primary-key-of-relational-database-table)